# How to change file name in a directory using cut command or any other process

Tags: bash, cut

I have many files in a directory like below using cut the "-" character on particular places or any other solution

```
file-2018-09-07-02
file-2017-07-08-03
file-2018-05-09-04
file-2017-03-10-05
file-2016-10-11-06
```

and so on ..... , How can I convert them to as below

```
file-2018090702
file-2017070803
file-2018050904
file-2017031005
file-2016101106
```

Answer (score 0):

If you *have* to use `cut`, then use a loop:

```
for file in file-????-??-??-??; do                        # pick up all matches for the glob
  [[ -f $file ]] || continue                              # skip if not a regular file
  new_name=$(cut -c1-5,6-9,11,12,14,15,17,18 <<< "$file") # generate new name
  mv "$file" "$new_name"                                  # move!
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Just bash. This does not assume anything about the filename pattern:

```
for f in *; do
    new=$( IFS=-; set -f; set -- $f; new=$1; shift; [[ $# -gt 0 ]] && { IFS=; new+="-$*"; }; echo "$new" )
    [[ "$f" = "$new" ]] || echo mv "$f" "$new"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
rename -n 's/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})$/$1$2$3$4/' *
```

(remove -n switch when your tests are OK)

[image: warning] **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

If you run the following command (`GNU`)

```
$ file "$(readlink -f "$(type -p rename)")"
```

and you have a result like

```
.../rename: Perl script, ASCII text executable
```

and not containing:

```
ELF
```

then this seems to be the right tool =)

If not, to make it the default (usually already the case) on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --set rename /path/to/rename
```

(replace `/path/to/rename` to the path of your `perl's rename` command.

---

If you don't have this command, search your package manager to install it or [do it manually](https://web.archive.org/web/20130625192518/https://metacpan.org/module/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL)

---

Last but not least, this tool was originally written by Larry Wall, the Perl's dad.